# Need help accessing Key Values in a nested Object of Objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

So I am getting Data from a firestore document that comes out to look like this.
`{xgvppy7455eeyjllj62yuf: {…}, sorxzerz1ynvy1urmllkdk: {…}, K3N7U2ThQCPVUl4b4rWAfVJiP2d2: {…}}`
The encrypted stuff is just the ID I use to identify the fields in the document, now they have objects in them that look like this.

[image]

```
K3N7U2ThQCPVUl4b4rWAfVJiP2d2:
  balance: "208843"
  description: "Rainy Day"
  name: "Rainy Day Pod"

sorxzerz1ynvy1urmllkdk:
  balance: "214352"
  description: "Sammiched"
  name: "Sammich"
```

How can I access just the value of the description key in both objects?

Aplogies, heres my code for getting the document data.

```
var docRef = db.collection("pods").doc("K3N7U2ThQCPVUl4b4rWAfVJiP2d2");


docRef.get().then(function(doc) {
if (doc.exists) {
    console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
```

Comment: I recommend editing the question to include 1) the code you have now 2) the data in the database using a screenshot, so we can more clearly see the data you're working with, 3) what you've tried that doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks! Just did!

Comment: Please post the raw JSON, I don't know why a user with 180k rep would ask you to post a screenshot of your data. That's not the correct way to ask a question.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce The screenshot is helpful so that we can see that the data is actually a single document and not a query full of documents.  The question was not very clear on this point, since it didn't include code (and still doesn't include code).  Usually, though, people provide desktop screenshots rather than photos.

Comment: {sorxzerz1ynvy1urmllkdk: {…}, K3N7U2ThQCPVUl4b4rWAfVJiP2d2: {…}, xgvppy7455eeyjllj62yuf: {…}}K3N7U2ThQCPVUl4b4rWAfVJiP2d2: {name: "Rainy Day Pod", balance: "208843", description: "Rainy Day"}sorxzerz1ynvy1urmllkdk: {description: "Sammiched", name: "Sammich", balance: "214352"}xgvppy7455eeyjllj62yuf: {description: "Sammiched", name: "Sammich", balance: "214352"}__proto__: Object
Thanks! @Iwrestledabearonce.

Comment: @DougStevenson. Apologies and put in the excerpt of the code, I am getting the entire document from firestore and want to get the description from each object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`doc.data()` returns a plain JavaScript object whose properties and values match the fields of the document.  It looks like each of your random strings is a separate field in the document, which means they would be the properties of the returned object.

You can use any of the techniques from [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties) to iterate the properties of a JavaScript object.  For example:

```
const data = doc.data()
for (field in data) {
    console.log(field)       // logs the random field name
    console.log(data[field)) // logs the object data of that field
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate the whole object, regardless of the key (which is hashed).
To iterate an object you could do:

```
const obj = {... some data with hashed keys ...}

Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
    const value = obj[key];
    const description = value.description;
    // ... do something with the description;
});
```

Comment: Thanks! But for some reason, it only returns one of the values!

Comment: This is a really good answer btw! Engineered it to work, thanks!